# Odoo - can write method cause memory leak when using 5 and 3 commands?

Tags: python, orm, odoo, odoo-13

I’m wondering if incorrectly used `write` method can lead to a “memory leak”.

Let’s suppose that I have some Sale Order that I need to recompute. So I would remove all previous order lines and then in a loop I would create new lines like this:

```py
sale_order.write({'order_line':[(5, 0, 0)]}) # Remove all previous products

vals = []
for product in new_products:
    vals.append((0, 0, {'product_id': product.id, 'product_uom_qty': product.qty, …})) # Create new lines

sale_order.write({'order_line':vals}) # Add new lines
```

But in the documentation it says, that `(5, 0, 0)` is equivalent of calling `(3, id, 0)` for every id, and that this command does not deletes records from the database (only  `(2, id, 0)` does).

So if I'm understanding correctly if I would run this code couple of times at the end I would be left with many lines that do not correspond to any order and just exist in the database?

If so - how should I do this without causing this leak? Do I need to use `2` instead of `3/5` commands?

Using Odoo13.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use `unlink` on the order lines field:

```py
sale_order.order_line.unlink()
```